# How to make a resizable rectangle in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qquickitem

I'm looking for a simple way to create a rectangle in a `QQuickItem`.
I want to resize, and drag the borders of this rectangle like this (found at [resizable `QRubberBand`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066804/implementing-resize-handles-on-qrubberband-is-qsizegrip-relevant))

[image]

Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are probably several ways to achieve the desired result. Since I've considered the implementation of a similar `Component` for a cropping tool software of mine, I'm going to share a toy example which uses part of that code.

Differently from the rubber band in the example, my `Rectangle` is resizable only on a single axis at a time. I'm confident that you can build on that and customise the code to meet your needs.

The basic idea of the code is to exploit the [`drag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#drag-prop) property of `MouseArea`. It can be used to move around the `Rectangle` and, combined with [`MouseX`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseX-prop) and [`MouseY`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseY-prop) properties, resize it.

Dragging is active inside the `Rectangle` whereas resizing is active on the knobs set on the sides of the `Rectangle` (no mouse cursor change is set for the sake of brevity).

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Test Crop")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    property var selection: undefined

    Image {
        id: image1
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/l-Kitty-attack.jpg"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if(!selection)
                    selection = selectionComponent.createObject(parent, {"x": parent.width / 4, "y": parent.height / 4, "width": parent.width / 2, "height": parent.width / 2})
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: selectionComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: selComp
            border {
                width: 2
                color: "steelblue"
            }
            color: "#354682B4"

            property int rulersSize: 18

            MouseArea {     // drag mouse area
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag{
                    target: parent
                    minimumX: 0
                    minimumY: 0
                    maximumX: parent.parent.width - parent.width
                    maximumY: parent.parent.height - parent.height
                    smoothed: true
                }

                onDoubleClicked: {
                    parent.destroy()        // destroy component
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: rulersSize
                height: rulersSize
                radius: rulersSize
                color: "steelblue"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis }
                    onMouseXChanged: {
                        if(drag.active){
                            selComp.width = selComp.width - mouseX
                            selComp.x = selComp.x + mouseX
                            if(selComp.width < 30)
                                selComp.width = 30
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: rulersSize
                height: rulersSize
                radius: rulersSize
                color: "steelblue"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.right
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis }
                    onMouseXChanged: {
                        if(drag.active){
                            selComp.width = selComp.width + mouseX
                            if(selComp.width < 50)
                                selComp.width = 50
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: rulersSize
                height: rulersSize
                radius: rulersSize
                x: parent.x / 2
                y: 0
                color: "steelblue"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.top

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                    onMouseYChanged: {
                        if(drag.active){
                            selComp.height = selComp.height - mouseY
                            selComp.y = selComp.y + mouseY
                            if(selComp.height < 50)
                                selComp.height = 50
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            Rectangle {
                width: rulersSize
                height: rulersSize
                radius: rulersSize
                x: parent.x / 2
                y: parent.y
                color: "steelblue"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.bottom

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                    onMouseYChanged: {
                        if(drag.active){
                            selComp.height = selComp.height + mouseY
                            if(selComp.height < 50)
                                selComp.height = 50
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A screenshot of the example:
[image]

Comment: Nice example and nice kitty!

Comment: I have tested this code and on my machine it seems that the dragging works only using bottom handle, the other 3 handles fail to be dragged/moved

Comment: Can't test it on Windows right now but a quick test on my Fedora 29 laptop showed a perfectly fine behaviour.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Nice example. Mind if I re-use it in one of my apps?

Comment: @user826955 of course. Feel free to come back and update the code with improvements - or provide your own answer if you radically change the code. That way everyone can benefit. As a matter of fact this is just a demo code. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
MouseArea {
            id:roiRectArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressed: {
                pressX = mouse.x
                pressY = mouse.y
            }

            onReleased: {
                releaseX = mouse.x
                releaseY = mouse.y
                rectWidth = releaseX
                widthRect = releaseX - pressX
                rectHeight = releaseY
                heightRect = releaseY - pressY
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                releaseX = mouse.x
                releaseY = mouse.y
                widthRect = releaseX - pressX
                heightRect = releaseY - pressY
            }

            Rectangle {
                id:rectRoi
                antialiasing: true
                opacity: 0.4
                x: pressX
                y: pressY
                width: widthRect
                height: heightRect
                border {
                    width: 2
                    color: "blue"
                }
                color: "#00F0F8FF"

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag{
                        target: rectRoi
                        minimumX: 0
                        minimumY: 0
                        maximumX: parent.parent.width - parent.width
                        maximumY: parent.parent.height - parent.height
                        smoothed: true
                    }
                    onDoubleClicked: {
                        parent.destroy()
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: rulersSize
                    height: rulersSize
                    color: "white"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.top
                    id: selComp
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis }
                        onMouseXChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){
                                var newWidth = rectRoi.width - mouseX
                                if (newWidth < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.width = newWidth
                                rectRoi.x = rectRoi.x + mouseX
                            }
                        }
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                        onMouseYChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){
                                var newHeight = rectRoi.height - mouseY;

                                if (newHeight < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.height = newHeight
                                rectRoi.y = rectRoi.y + mouseY
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: rulersSize
                    height: rulersSize
                    color: "red"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.left
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.bottom

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis; }
                        onMouseXChanged: {
                            if(drag.active) {
                                var newWidth = rectRoi.width - mouseX
                                if (newWidth < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.width = newWidth
                                rectRoi.x = rectRoi.x + mouseX
                            }
                        }
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                        onMouseYChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){

                                var newHeight = rectRoi.height + mouseY;

                                if (newHeight < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.height = newHeight
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: rulersSize
                    height: rulersSize
                    color: "orange"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.right
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.bottom
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis }
                        onMouseXChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){

                                var newWidth = rectRoi.width + mouseX
                                if (newWidth < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.width = newWidth
                            }
                        }
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                        onMouseYChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){

                                var newHeight = rectRoi.height + mouseY;

                                if (newHeight < 30)
                                    return
                                rectRoi.height = newHeight
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: rulersSize
                    height: rulersSize
                    color: "green"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.right
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.top
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.XAxis; }
                        onMouseXChanged: {
                            if(drag.active){

                                var newWidth = repeater.itemAt(index).width + mouseX
                                if (newWidth < 30)
                                    return
                                repeater.itemAt(index).width = newWidth
                            }
                        }
                        drag{ target: parent; axis: Drag.YAxis }
                        onMouseYChanged: {
                            if(drag.active) {
                                var newHeight = repeater.itemAt(index).height - mouseY;
                                if (newHeight < 30)
                                    return
                                repeater.itemAt(index).height = newHeight
                                repeater.itemAt(index).y = repeater.itemAt(index).y + mouseY
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help someone