# Qt: How to change Rubberband selection color

Tags: qt

Qt : I have Subclass the Qgraphicsview and handling mouse events and Set the Dragmode as RubberBandDrag

```
setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
```

I am getting the rubberband selection but I am not able to customize the rubberband selection color. Please suggest .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that will take the system color.

The cleanest way to do it is by subclassing QRubberBand or, better, create your own rubber band as a QWidget containing a QRubberBand (allows you to customize even more the rubber band).

Take look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066804/implementing-resize-handles-on-qrubberband-is-qsizegrip-relevant), it made my day sometime ago.

If you are going to write cross-platform code, keep in mind that on recent osX versions cocoa does not draw the size grips, so you have to draw them in your paint event (under #ifdef Q_OS_MAC).